# Loopback Logout from React returns 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: reactjs, loopbackjs, axios

I'm getting `401 (Unauthorized)` error when i try LogOut using axios from the front-end, even though **Logout works from the Loopback User Interface or Postman**

```
handleLogout() {
   let access_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token')
   axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/Users/logout', {
     data: access_token
   })
 }
```

I also tried

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/Users/logout', {
  access_token: access_token
})
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How is that token used server-side? Is it a JWT?

Comment: It's auto generated by [loopback](https://loopback.io/)

Comment: Okay but where does your API expects that token to be stored when making requests? In the headers (most likely), and if yes, under what header entry/name? Or does it expect it as a URL querystring? Or in the body of the request?

Comment: the request should be this `http://localhost:3000/api/Users?access_token=SlwnFrBt9KcMihz7bcmZ315wlbcqDcQDfdG5vTDeU7ClkeyV4As5Hvvn6NzdChnm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the token is expected as a query-string param, as indicated in your comment, try the following:

```
handleLogout() {
  axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/api/Users/logout?access_token=${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`);
}
```

Although are you positive a POST method is expected? There is no data being passed (as one would expect from a POST request), although it might make sense if the User can be identified through the token.

Comment: I was looking for something more elegant, but this will do lol. Why do i never think of easy solutions ><

Comment: @CristianMuscalu I know what you mean :D Maybe there's a way for you to configure your auth process to use headers instead to handle that token, with a header name like `authorization`. Then the request would look different. But like you said, whatever works, works.